# Creating a REST route like /users/new

Tags: scala, playframework

Is it possible to create a REST endpoint in play like:

```
/users/new
```

That would also call a method named `new` ?

I tried doing this like:

```
  def `new`:= {
    ...
  }
```

The action worked fine, but the line in my route file was not working because of the new keyword:

```
GET   /users/new            @controllers.UserController.new
```

I like following the rubyonrails convention with URL endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a expert but try this:

```
GET   /users/new            @controllers.UserController.new()
```

Also your function new() is under UserController class?

new is reserved word in Java at least. I made successfully  controller:

```
GET     /user/new   controllers.UserController.news()
```